# WatchKit EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error after updating to OS2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple-watch

I'am updating my app for IOS9 and Watch OS2. But i getting on the Watch app a EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOPE, subcode=0x0) error on this line when i start the simulator:

```
func update_nowplaying(){
    Artist.setText(blogPosts[0].postArtist)
    ArtistTitle.setText(blogPosts[0].postTitle)
}
```

When i change this to Artist.setText("Hello") and ArtistTitle.setText("World") then it works.

Here some more code:
In BlogPost.swift:

```
class BlogPost {
    var postArtist: String = String()
    var postTitle: String = String()
    var postTime: String = String()
}
```

And the XML parser:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    eName = elementName
    if elementName == "song" {
        postArtist = String()
        postTitle = String()
        postTime = String()
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?) {
    let data = string!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    if (!data.isEmpty) {
        if eName == "artist" {
            postArtist += data
        } else if eName == "title" {
            postTitle += data
        } else if eName == "timeplayed" {
            postTime += data
        }
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "song" {
        let blogPost: BlogPost = BlogPost()
        blogPost.postArtist = postArtist
        blogPost.postTitle = postTitle
        blogPost.postTime = postTime
        blogPosts.append(blogPost)
        }}
```

I don't get it. This same peace of code works in the main app and in the previous version of my app. So why won't this work with OS2?

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the exact error message provided by Xcode and on the exact line, please?

There's a good chance you are running into any one of the following

- nil reference on blogPosts
- nil reference on the subscript 0 for blogPosts (meaning, nothing at[0])
- nil reference on .postArtist or .postTitle

Having the exact error message from the console will help shed some light on this.

Comment: Got it working, a https issue. The XML url needs to be https since Swift 2.0? Works fine now in Simulator, but a crash on the Apple Watch device it self. Can not find why :(